# How can I solve the error when accessing facebook login

Tags: flutter

I am new in mobile application. I am trying to do facebook login. I followed this Sample application  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_connect
 but I am getting error in facebook page like this-
                           "**cannot load URl: this domain URL is not included in api domain. to enable this url uploaded, enter all your app domains and subdomains on the api domain field in your app settings**".

Comment: Have you created an app on developer.facebook.com yet, and added `http://localhost:8080` to the app domain fields?

Comment: Can you show us how did you use the plugin? and how did you link it with your facebook app ?

Comment: Hi Baksteen, I created the app in  developer.facebook.com but not added anything in app domain. I have not hosted anything on my local server so how can I give this "http://localhost:8080".

Comment: Hi aziza, First I created app in developer.facebook.com at that time I got 'APP_ID' and 'CLIENT_SECRET'. After that, I added facebook plugin in my application [flutter_facebook_connect]. This is the code I used in raisedbutton pressed                                                                             final _facebookConnect = new FacebookConnect(
          appId: '<APP_ID>',
          clientSecret: '<CLIENT_SECRET');

FacebookOAuthToken token = await _facebookConnect.login();                   I Noticed that the note [Redirection Url need to be http://localhost:8080] how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
_facebookSignIn() async {
        final _facebookConnect = new FacebookConnect(
            appId: '<APP_ID>',
            clientSecret: '<CLIENT_SECRET>');
        FacebookOAuthToken token = await _facebookConnect.login();

     //FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithFacebook(accessToken: token.access);
       // return user;}
```

You have to follow the instructions at developers.facebook, and add `http://localhost:8080` in your app Settings under Products>MyApp>Settings

[image]